# “…not less controversy in it but more." vs "…not less but more controversy in it." Are both correct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I can think of two variants of this sentence, which are intended to have the same meaning:

> 1. There was not less controversy in it but more.
> 2. There was not less but more controversy in it.

In the adduced sentences, ***it*** refers to science .

I'm not sure which of them is correct.

Comment: Would you give us the preceding sentence for more context?

Answer (score -1):

As for quantum theory, there was not less controversy in it, but more.

As for quantum theory, there was not less, but more, controversy.

Insertion of a comma makes the meaning of the first clearer, and preferable because it brings controversy (which is the object) to attention earlier in the reading of the sentence. I believe both are grammatically acceptable.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The subject of quantum mechanics is not at issue. No related drama is required. It is too unusual to add parenthetical phrases with commas ad libidum. It is perfectly normal (what they are asking about) for the usage of "not less controversy in it but more".

Comment: The mention of quantum mechanics is merely exemplary of the usage and  has nothing to do with adding drama, which you attribute to me gratuitously. Your appreciation of my concluding remark (with which you seem to agree) is clouded by your misunderstanding of that point.  As for your (delightfully saucy-sounding) ad libidum  (sic), the commas are exactly that - as often as necessary or as desired.

Comment: -@Anton Glad you agree. But my comment remains; It is too unusual for a sentence to add such parenthetical phrases on and on. The earlier sentence is much preferred.